# For loops in R: how to save results of a loop to an object

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop

I would like to save the output of this function as an object.

It prints the output I need but I can not save it as an object (if I do the content in NULL).

```
# Data Sample 
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                  var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
                  var2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1))
df1$var1 <- factor(df1$var1)


# Function 
make_test <- function(data_set){
  
  variable <- ifelse(sapply(data_set, is.factor), "factor", "not_factor")
  
  res <- ""
  cat("intro", "\n")
  for(i in 1:length(variable)){
    if(variable[i]=="factor"){
      res <- cat("text1", "\n")
    }
    else{
      res <- cat("text2", "\n")
    }
    res
  }
  cat("conclusion", "\n")
}
```

This is the output if I apply the function to df1

```
> make_test(df1)
intro 
text2 
text1 
text2 
conclusion
```

I need to save this text because later I will save it in an R file using

```
write(object_name, file = paste0(data_set, ".R"))
```

Comment: What output are you hoping to capture? Everything from your `cat` calls?

Comment: added the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the values generated in your loop in an object. Then your function can return that object:

```r
make_test <- function(data_set){
  
  variable <- ifelse(sapply(data_set, is.factor), "factor", "not_factor")
  
  res <- vector(mode = "character", length = length(variable))
  for(i in 1:length(variable)){
    if(variable[i]=="factor"){
      res[i] <- "text1\n"
    }
    else{
      res[i] <- "text2\n"
    }
  }
  res <- c("intro\n", res, "conclusion\n")
  return(res)
}

obj <- make_test(df1)
obj
[1] "intro\n"      "text2\n"      "text1\n"      "text2\n"      "conclusion\n"
```

By default, `cat` only prints to the console and is not stored anywhere.

You can also clean up your `for` loop conditions by using `is.factor` directly:

```r
make_test <- function(data_set) {
  
  res <- vector(mode = "character", length = ncol(data_set))
  
  for (i in seq_along(data_set)){
    if (is.factor(data_set[[i]])){
      res[i] <- "text1\n"
    } else {
      res[i] <- "text2\n"
    }
  }
  res <- c("intro\n", res, "conclusion\n")
  return(res)
}
```

or simply:

```r
obj <- c("intro", ifelse(lapply(df1, is.factor), "test1", "test2"), "conclusion")
```

Comment: These two solutions are doing the same thing mine is doing + the text is not showing up in the next line anymore. I still cannot save the output as an object.
If you try you solution outside the function you will see that the object has NULL.

Comment: @Mando, no they are not doing the same thing. You are printing to the screen, these functions are returning a value that can then be subsequently used. What are you trying to accomplish with the values "intro", "test1", etc.?

Comment: Try your solution outside the function and you will see that your object has nothing. the only purpose is to return the printed text in the console

Comment: If the only purpose is to print text to the console, then why are you trying to "save" results and why isn't the function you wrote giving you what you need?

Comment: the only purpose of your solution and mine. I need to save it as an object to be able to create a file with the output.

Comment: You need to assign the output after the function call to save it as an object. See my update. I was not assigning it to simply show the output of the call.